# Measure real, system time for each command

Tags: c++, performance, time

I have a c++ executable which for which real time is much greater than user and sys time. I suspect this is because of I/O wait. I want to measure real and user time for each line/function to determine what is consuming time.

Is there any way to measure it?

Comment: [Clocks](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono#Clocks)

Comment: My code base is very huge. Writing clocks would be tedious. Is there any other way?

Comment: One usually use a software profiler to analyze performance. One can usually see how many ms each function uses. I have never profiled a C++ program, so I can't recommend any to you. But I assume Visual Studio have some form of profiler.

Comment: Use profilers gprof, google perftools etc.

Comment: @NipunTalukdar Using gprof, how do I determine real, sys time for each function?

Comment: MSVS has this built in if you are using it(I think it started with version 2015).

Comment: @Rajs123 there is no way to get real, sys time for each func from gprof output. But still you may get an idea about where the most CPU time is being spent.

Comment: I want to determine the command where most amount of real - cpu time is spent

Comment: You can use Intel's PinTool to write your own profiler. But it will take time as you will have to get accustomed with its development environment.